# Encog Image Recognition, Invalid command Error

Tags: java, image, encog

I am trying to run image recognition code in Encog framework.

[This](https://github.com/jeffheaton/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/image/ImageNeuralNetwork.java) one

But I am having problems with the input. I am getting the following error

[image]

I am trying to get the picture into the program. I did it the following way.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    /*
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out
                .println("Must specify command file.  See source for format.");
    } else {

     */

    String string = "/Users/hehe/Downloads/Screenshot_2023-01-08_at_08.11.24-removebg-preview.png";
    try {
        final ImageNeuralNetwork program = new ImageNeuralNetwork();
        program.execute(string);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
}
```

I commented first part of the code because I can't run this program in command line.

When I try to compile it like this

javac /Users/hehe/IdeaProjects/TestRencognition/src/main/java/ImageNeuralNetwork.java

I am getting error that the package org.encog does not exist

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: There are two different problems there. Your larger one is of understanding, and I'm guessing you haven't read the documentation. How could a png file be a "command file"?